# GitHub Action failes building firebase app w9jds/firebase-action

Tags: node.js, firebase, github, npm, github-actions

I can deploy my friebase app (https://github.com/Luuuuuis/profile-page) using `firebase deploy` in my local command line, but when I push it it keep failing -> No code error.

This is my GitHub Action:  https://github.com/Luuuuuis/profile-page/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml
and it fails when trying to build. https://github.com/Luuuuuis/profile-page/runs/792416930?check_suite_focus=true

This is the error I get:

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/storage-engine/lib/compatibility/index.js'
at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1194:35)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/storage-engine/lib/compatibility/detect.js:35:15
at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/storage-engine/lib/compatibility/detect.js:45:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! storage-engine@3.0.7 postinstall: node ./compatibility/detect.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the storage-engine@3.0.7 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-21T10_52_59_937Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g firebase-tools' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]Docker build failed with exit code 1`

It already worked yesterday, but when I tried it today multiple times it didn't work. Is something wrong with my action?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, it was fine yesterday, now it's not. Looking forward to seeing an answer there...

Comment: It seems to be some issue with the permissions on the container that `firebase-action` is using. Someone has already reported [this issue](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/issues/46) on their Github page.

Comment: oh ok so it their fault. Ok then I'll have to wait

Comment: More users seems impacted @see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2383 and https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/issues/46

Answer (score 3):

try using the --unsafe-perm flag or configure an env variable:
NPM_CONFIG_USER root

Answer (score 0):

This is more for others coming to see this question, maybe for related, but not exact problems. For the specific original problem, the issues seems to be a firebase issue. But, if like me, you had a similar problem with permissions (as pointed out in phyyyl's answer), this is how I fixed it.

To bypass the permissions, I used the explanation found in [the npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally). So install without the `-g` flag and use `npx`, which recognizes that the installed program was not installed globally. I use netlify, so not sure what the equivalent firebase would be. But I hope this helps.

```
deploy:
    image: node:latest
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - npm install netlify-cli
    script:
        - npx netlify deploy --dir public
```

Answer (score -1):

```
EACCES: permission denied
```

You should try execute it with `sudo`

Comment: But how can I use sudo in github actions?

Comment: I see. It seems like a problem with installing the package globally. Maybe you find a way to use firebase-tools when installed locally without -g. I found some other ways here but idk if they work with github actions: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: but why did it work yesterday? I do not unterstand how I should I run it without -g when I use this premade action. The guy makeing this action tought -g would be good?